# Text notification R

Tags: r, sms

I run simulations in R that often take a long time (days or weeks). Is is possible to have R send me an SMS notification when the simulations finish?

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365657/is-there-a-way-to-make-r-beep-play-a-sound-at-the-end-of-a-script) that it's possible to set up an `alarm` but I don't see how to set up text notifications.

Comment: what platform are you on? you could do this in one-line shell script by emailing yournumber@youcarrierSMSaddress.com instead of using an r emailing package

Comment: I generally use Windows Server 2012 but I also use OS applications. If possible, I'd prefer to use R in case I switch platforms.

Comment: pushbullet? https://www.pushbullet.com/ and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPushbullet/index.html

Comment: This may be of use: https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/notifications-from-r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code that will send you notifications using RPushbullet:

```
library(RPushbullet)
pbPost(title="Simulations are completed",
  apikey="KEY HERE", #API key is found in account settings
  devices="DEVICE ID HERE") #Device ID's are found on devices page.
```

The `apikey` is located in your account settings (and is free)

The device id's can be found by clicking on each device and pasting the value(s) following the equal signs (shown by the X's below).

www.pushbullet.com/?device_iden=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

As noted in the comments, more sophisticated approaches are described [here](https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/notifications-from-r/) and [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rpushbullet.html).