# Setup R alert when long process is Finished

Tags: r, rstudio, alert

I'm running a really long process and it would be great if there was a way to get R to Call, Email or Text me when its finished.  Is there a way to setup an R-email script to be run when a program terminates or perhaps something that might employ IFTTT to send me a text message or Call in case I'm sleeping.

I'm using RStudio as my IDE so maybe there is such a feature through there.

If there is a way to track progress that would be nice too, but not 100% required

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this article:

http://alicebrawley.com/getting-r-to-notify-you-when-its-finished/

> My general solution is to combine the R package mail, written by Lin
>   Himmelmann, and variations on an IFTTT (If This, Then That) recipe. I
>   use mail to send an email using functions in R, then IFTTT to notify
>   me immediately of that particular email.
>
> Once you’ve installed mail, use the following functions to send
>   yourself an email when your code is completed.

```
#Have R email you when it's done running.
###Calculating - your wish is R's command.
library(mail)
#Send yourself an email - specify your preferred email address, subject, and message. The password is fixed at "rmail".
sendmail("xxxxx@xxxxx.com", subject="Notification from R", message="Conditions finished running!", password="rmail")
```

You can then use IFTT triggered by the email.

If you're sleeping next to your computer, consider also:  [Is there a way to make R beep/play a sound at the end of a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365657/is-there-a-way-to-make-r-beep-play-a-sound-at-the-end-of-a-script)

Comment: Where is the email sent from? Do i need to provide my own email and password?

Comment: @adam it's sent from the package author's server.  You just need to pass your receiving email address.

Comment: I know this should be closed by now, but `sendmail("myemail@domain.com")` started returning `"Problem!"`.  Is there a reason for that?  How would I fix this? I've tried multiple different addresses on different domains

Comment: @Adam I believe the API calls are throttled (to prevent spam).  If you are doing a lot of these calls you may want to try `gmailr` or another email package that uses your imap account