# Make R/RStudio beep play after *every* command

Tags: r, rstudio

My question relates to [making R beep after a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365657/is-there-a-way-to-make-r-beep-play-a-sound-at-the-end-of-a-script). I understand that I can run `beep()` together with whatever command I want to run, but is there a way to *automatically* run `beep()` (from `beepr` package) or `system("say done")` (I run RStudio on a Mac) after *every* command?

e.g. is there a `options()` setting I can tweak so that after entering every command in the interpreter another command like `beep()` is executed?

Comment: To clarify: You want to play a sound every time you send code from RStudio to R? I don't think RStudio supports this. Thus, you'd need to hook into R's REPL and AFAIK that's not possible (without changing R's source code and recompiling it). If you were using `source` you could add the beeping to its source code easily, but that's probably not what you are doing.

Comment: right. basically just a fuss free way of making sure it beeps after every command

Comment: See [this R-help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/260433.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [addTaskCallback](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/taskCallback.html).

```
addTaskCallback(function(...) { system("say done"); TRUE }, name = "announce when done")
```

Have fun!